# Where should I put list of UserControls and not break MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a tab control where each TabItem is a UserControl.  I'd like to hold the UserControls in the TabControl's ItemsSource.  Does ItemsSource list go in the Window's ViewModel?  If so, I feel like it's breaking MVVM since the ViewModel would now have GUI controls within it. Or do I put this list in the codebehind of the window that holds the tab control?

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've done.
I created an interface that all of my controls implement, IMyAppControl, which has some information such as Title, Description, other metadata.

My Main Window has an ObservableCollection that the tab ItemsSource binds to.

Answer (score 0):

With tab controls, more often than not the individual tabs are created statically in XAML rather than at run time by data binding. However there is no reason why you shouldn't do this. If you have a collection of views, they should definitely be stored in a view.

Bear in mind that you could also bind the ItemsSource to a list of ViewModels objects and WPF will generate a view for you with the ItemTemplate, with the ViewModel object set as the DataContext. This collection of ViewModels should be stored in a view model, although at some point a view model will obviously have to be stored in a view.

Answer (score 0):

This can most likely be done in a number of ways, all which are up for debate on how "MVVM-friendly" they are.

My setup looks like the following.

My Main window has a DataContext bound to a MainWindowViewModel which contains an property

```
public ObservableCollection<Workspace> WorkspaceCollection{get;set;}
```

MainWindow has a `TabControl` which `ItemsSource` is bound to `WorkspaceCollection`

Workspace are all viewmodels and are bound to different views/usercontrols via DataTemplates

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the **Write** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It has a TabControl where each TabItem is a UserControl and it does this by applying the MVVM pattern.